# Argument list too long - No command is working in VS Code

Tags: linux, shell, visual-studio-code, terminal, command-line-arguments

I am getting this `Argument list too long` error whenever, I run any command in VS code.
All commands are working in the Linux default terminal but nothing is working in VS code terminal.

Here is the error-
[image]

I read a few solutions but I didn't understand all of them. Those are:

1. Remove the entire directory and recreate it.

   - How this can be a solution because this error is happening in all projects. Would I remove all project directories and recreate them?
2. Mass delete files using the find method?

   - My all projects are cloned from git. Even if I delete all files of a project then to recreate them, I need to re-clone which I tried, and that is not working.
3. Change the limit using the command - `ulimit -s <any_number_greater_than_current_limit>`

   - It didn't work.

I checked my max limit of arguments, using those two commands-

[image]

What am I doing wrong or misunderstood?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error?

Comment: I don't see a concrete command and the error message. Since you claim that the message comes on **every** command, does it mean that even if you run - for instance - the command `pwd`, you would get an _argument list too long_?

Comment: I added the screenshot. @carlfriedrich

Comment: pwd, cd, history, etc. commands are working fine. Mostly git commands, and bash commands are not working. @user1934428

Comment: Command line length counts against the same limit as environment variables.

Comment: So this means you've `export`ed too much data. Keep your shell variables on the heap instead of in the environment whenever you can.

Comment: The commands that still work are built into the shell, so running them doesn't involve an `execve` syscall, which is where the length limit is applied.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer, I will try. A question, then why every command is working in the Linux default terminal? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can audit your environment variables as follows: `(while IFS= read -r -d '' var; do printf '%s=%q\n' "${var%%=*}" "${var#*=}"; done </proc/self/environ)`

Comment: Each process has its own environment. It's not shared with the terminal, except insofar as each program's environment is initialized from the program that started it, but then can be changed from there.

Comment: Anyhow, once you look at what's going on in your environment, hopefully something will stand out and make the solution obvious. (You can remove a variable with `unset`).

Comment: To pick up the valid argument by Charles Duffy: What happens if you enter the command `command pwd`? This should bypass the shell builtin and run an external one. While a huge environment could be in theory the culprit, it would be a bit unlikely that it is so big that it is at the verge of effecting **every** child process with arguments.  Can you run a lone `printenv` or `env`?

Comment: BTW, if `printenv` and `env` don't work (they are external commands after all), you can also execute the internal command `declare`. Different to `printenv`, this lists all variables, not only environment variables, but it should at least give you a reasonable idea how full your process space is. If you are lucky, redirection works (i.e. `declare >/tmp/vars.txt`), which will allow you to study the output afterwards using a text editor.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `printenv` and `env` is not working, however, the `declare` command worked. @user1934428

Comment: So, can you say now whether the culprit is the environment, as Charles Duffy suspected?

Comment: Hey, as you guys suggested, @CharlesDuffy, and @user1934428 I checked my `.bashrc file`. I noticed one thing the env variable `path` was set like this- `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"` and this path was written almost 10000+ times. I removed all lines and leave only a single one, reload the shell, and the error is gone. Does it make sense? Was memory consumed by this env variable PATH which was exported a thousand times?

Comment: @NehaSoni, yup, that explains it. Think about changing that code to only add to the PATH if the item it needs is not already there: `[[ $PATH =~ (^|.*:)"$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"($|:.*) ]] || PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` -- you don't need the quotes in an assignment when the right-hand side isn't otherwise ambiguous, and you don't need the `export` when changing a variable that's _already_ exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question, I tried several ways which didn't work for me.

In my case, I checked the `.bashrc` file and found that the `PATH` variable was exported almost 10000+ times like that-

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/
...
...
...
```

That is what consumed the space and make the memory full to run any further commands even with 0 arguments.

I removed all and added the following script to define `PATH` only when not added already.

```
[[ $PATH =~ (^|.*:)"$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"($|:.*) ]] || PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

I reload the shell then and it worked.

Thanks, @CharlesDuffy for your suggestions.